# CQRS and Session

Tags: session, cqrs

I'm a great fan of CQRS but there is something I still can't figure out : how would you describe a login process in CQRS ? because it's a query (checking the credentials) and a command (creating the in-memory/sql/whatever session state). 
And in this case we can't have an asynchronous command, a login process must be synchronous.

Or maybe the concept of session doesn't exists in CQRS because it implies some sort of state ?

Rémi

Comment: What about the process of creating a new entity - how do you get the new Id?

Comment: This can be made asynchronous, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely depends upon your situation.

The question is: what does logging in *mean* in your application?

If it just means that the user is authenticated and a session cookie is stored in his browser, then you can achieve that just by reading. Your login procedure could, for instance, be mostly client-side JavaScript code that does a login call by Ajax; the login call would simply read from the Read store (or an LDAP store, or other) and return a true/false result. Then the receiving client would create the cookie and the user is now considered logged in. The cookie may even contain username information.

If logging in means that a record of the login is stored in the database, as an event, then of course logging in means executing a `Command`. Here I suppose it would make sense to create a synchronous `Command` (and possibly a separate Login Service, after all this is plumbing).

Comment: How would a client receive a cookie ? It always seemed to me that a command returning a result is like a hack because a command is not supposed to return anything

Comment: The client would not receive a cookie from the server, it would set a cookie itself in JavaScript. As you can see above, that scenario doesn't execute a Command, it simply reads from the Read store or an Active Directory/LDAP to authenticate the user, then write a cookie locally.

Comment: The client creates the cookie but its value is created by the server isn't it ? I think I get your idea, it seems like ok for me, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Why would you want to use CQRS for authentification in the first place? It's a really bad fit.

You'd probably wrap your command handlers with some kind of authentification/authorization instead.

Remember, CQRS is not everywhere or nowhere. It's to be used on the Bounded Contexts on which it makes sense. User and session management usually isn't one of them.

Comment: Allow me to disagree. DDD and CQRS are different things and I know you know that. I can have a command: AuthenticateUser which authenticates the user and stores a token in a caching server. Saying that DDD is to be used in Bounded Contexts is not right.